# Want To Established RPC Connection B/W Two Mobile Devices?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket, network-programming, rpc

I am developing 8 pool games.For a send/receive position i am using
   RPC package.The connection is establishing connection b/w two
   different devices when its connected with same network (same ip).But
   when i am trying to establish connection with 3G data/Different wi-fi
   network it not working.

I used stun server to get public ip address of device but still its
   not working.Please let me know how can i establish connection b/w two
   different device with two different network.

Comment: What have you tried? What technologies you use? I see node, unity, websockets...

Comment: I tried android jar file which written in Java.I am able to get public ip of both the device but its not making connection b/w each other.